# Sending eth to two different addresses

Tags: solidity

I want to hard code a wallet address to which a small portion of eth will be sent each time an NFT is sold(basically a royalty feature).
Here are the functions of marketplace smart contract

```
address public royaltyAddress = 0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db;

function createMarketItem(
        address nftContract,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price
        ) public payable nonReentrant {
            require(price > 0, "Price must be greater than 0");
            
            _itemIds.increment();
            uint256 itemId = _itemIds.current();
  
            idToMarketItem[itemId] =  MarketItem(
                itemId,
                nftContract,
                tokenId,
                payable(msg.sender),
                payable(address(0)),
                price,
                false
            );
            
            IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
                
            emit MarketItemCreated(
                itemId,
                nftContract,
                tokenId,
                msg.sender,
                address(0),
                price,
                false
            );
        }
        
    function createMarketSale(
        address nftContract,
        uint256 itemId
        ) public payable nonReentrant {
            uint price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
            uint tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;
            bool sold = idToMarketItem[itemId].sold;
            require(msg.value == price, "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");
            require(sold != true, "This Sale has alredy finnished");
            emit MarketItemSold(
                itemId,
                msg.sender
                );

            idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value/2);
            // royaltyAddress.transfer(msg.value/3);
            IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
            idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
            _itemsSold.increment();
            idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
        }
```

when I uncomment this line inside createMarketSale: `royaltyAddress.transfer(msg.value/3);`

I get this error

```
TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".
```

How can I implement this feature?
Full nftMarketplace smart contract can be found here: https://github.com/ethereum-boilerplate/ethereum-nft-marketplace-boilerplate/blob/main/src/contracts/marketplaceBoilerplate.sol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variable as `address payable` before sending value to it.

You can do it once when you define the variable, and then use it:

```
address payable public royaltyAddress = payable(0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db);

...

royaltyAddress.transfer(msg.value/3);
```

Or you can do it only in the specific line you need:

```
payable(royaltyAddress).transfer(msg.value/3);
```